# expressjs write multiple middleware and import it to the main file

Tags: node.js, express

I have a script which holds a middleware like:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  req.requestTime = Date.now()
  next()
}
```

In a file I can import this but how can I write multiple middleware and export all of them and import it?

I am learning express and got stuck here :)

Comment: you can just write like the above as many middleware you need and just import it as object, or as  single like `module.exports.middleware1 = middleware1`, `module.exports.middleware2 = middleware2`

Comment: it's generally not a good idea to have multiple middleware in a file. Create a file for each of them. One file, one responsibility, one middleware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

write multiple middlewares in one file and exprot them all.

```
function middleware1(req, res, next) { req.requestTime = Date.now(); next() }
function middleware2(req, res, next) { req.requestTime = Date.now(); next() }
function middleware3(req, res, next) { req.requestTime = Date.now(); next() }

module.exports = {
    middleware1 : middleware1,
    middleware2 : middleware2,
    middleware3 : middleware3
}
```

then if you want to import them you can either import all of middlewares like

```
 var middleware = require("./middlewares") 
  // name of middleware file in require
```

then use them like

```
app.get('/profile', middleware.middleware1, function (req, res) {
   // do your stuff
});
```

Or you can import a single middleware by adding middleware function name in require

```
 var middleware1 = require("./middlewares").middleware1
```

then use them like

```
app.get('/profile', middleware1, function (req, res) {
   // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Please how can I specify that a middleware be used for all routes via app.use()?

Comment: yes, you can use app.use() to specify a middleware for all routes

Comment: Yes, I tried and these codes are working.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same, but my scenario was a bit different

I had type module in package.json

```
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

middleware file and exporting

```
const authenticate_middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
        const items = authHeader.split(' ');
        /*check count 2*/
        /*check 1st item is barner*/
        /*check and validate 2nd item*/
        const token = items[1];

        let user = {
            id: 1,
            token: token
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};

const developer_middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.developer;   /*all lower case apiKey was undefined*/
    if (authHeader) {
        let developer = {
            id: 1,
            apiKey: authHeader
        }
        req.developer = developer;
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};

export default authenticate_middleware;
export let authenticate = authenticate_middleware;
export let developer = developer_middleware;
```

importing modulewares

```
//import multiple
import { authenticate, developer } from '../middlewares/all.js'
//import single
import { developer } from '../middlewares/all.js'
// import default
import authenticate from '../middlewares/all.js'
```